# Accessing nested JSON elements in Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

New to Python and I'm not sure im encoding my request as JSON properly. I am trying to be able to access specific elements within the JSON. This is what I have:

```
import requests
import json

url = "sample.com"
access_token "xxxxx"

headers = {
    'authorization': access_token,
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

jsonvar = response.json()
print(jsonvar)
```

This gives me:

```
{u'sleep': 
     [{u'logId': 11208762595, 
       u'dateOfSleep': u'2016-03-23', 
       u'isMainSleep': True, 
       u'startTime': u'2016-03-22T23:43:30.000', 
       u'restlessCount': 7, 
       u'duration': 12540000, 
       u'restlessDuration': 13, 
       u'minuteData': [{u'value': u'2', u'dateTime': u'23:43:30'}, 
                       {u'value': u'1', u'dateTime': u'23:44:30'}],                         
       u'awakeCount': 1, 
       u'minutesAfterWakeup': 0}], 
 u'summary': 
      {u'totalTimeInBed': 418, 
       u'totalMinutesAsleep': 395, 
       u'totalSleepRecords': 2}}
```

I've altered the output in an attempt to make it more readable. Anyways I would like to assign specific element values to variables such as `isMainSleep` etc.

I've tried something like this:

```
myvar = jsonvar['isMainSleep']
```

I was able to get this to work in a different situation but none of the data was nested which seems to be the difference here.

Comment: `jsonvar['sleep']['isMainSleep']`

Comment: `isMainSleep` is in a dictionary nested inside a list nested inside another dictionary. You want `jsonvar[u'sleep'][0][u'isMainSleep']`. Notice the `u` in front because these are unicode strings and the `[0]` because it's the first item in the list. You might want to add some error checking.

Comment: @solarc your suggestion worked! However because its just a comment I can't accept it as the answer. Is there a better way to output this data so its actually in JSON format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to access each dictionary along the way. Like this:

```
myvar = jsonvar['sleep'][0]['isMainSleep']
```

You access the list associated with the key `sleep`, then its first element, which is a dictionary. Finally the value associated with the key `isMainSleep`.

Note that you do not need to add the prefix 'u' in front of your keys.

In answer to your comment, you could output this as a json like this:

```
print json.dumps(myvar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested list and dictionary here, and the top level keys are `sleep` and `summary`. So try `myvar = jsonvar['sleep'][0]['isMainSleep']`.